# Remove/handle UINavigationBar UIAppearence to fix issue in UIActivityViewController share screen title transparent after tapping more in Swift iOS

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiactivityviewcontroller, uiappearance

I've applied **UINavigationBar.appearence()** with use of class **UIAppearence()** throught out the app. Due to this facing issue while showing **UIActivityViewController()** share doc, I want to remove navigation bar appearence only while showing share doc screen and then navigationbar should be back as usual when we come back.

```
UINavigationBar.appearence()
```

I'm trying to share pdf file using **UIActivityViewController** in iPhone and iPad, Able to share with below code but facing issue after tapping (...)more it opens to select any app that **screen title(We have Done APPS and Edit button) is transparent**, title Background should come white as default.  Issue marked with red color rectangle. Title Background overrides with navigationbar appearence transparent property.

Let me know how to handle/remove appearence on navigationbar.

```
@objc func shareMenuTapped(button: UIBarButtonItem) {
     let url = NSURL.fileURL(withPath: "https://www.w3.org/WAI/ER/tests/xhtml/testfiles/resources/pdf/dummy.pdf") 
     let activityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [url], applicationActivities: nil)
     activityViewController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = self.shareButton // so that iPads won't crash, sharebutton is a rightbarbutton to navigation.
     self.present(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: nil) 
}
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the below code while presenting the `activityViewController`:

```
self.present(activityViewController, animated: true) { 
    UIBarButtonItem.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.systemBlue
    UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor.white
}
```